# 8x8 float32_t Matrix multiplication using ARM NEON is slower?

Tags: arm, matrix-multiplication, simd, neon

I'm wondering what intrinsics make the SIMD slower than normal matrix multiplication and what should I do to make the multiplication of large matrix faster using SIMD.  Here we have `matrixA[8][8]`, `matrixB[8][8]` and result `matrixC[8][8]`. Because the maximum number of elements for float32_t is 4, so I did 2 vmul and vadd, which seem to be quite not optimized. I work on ARMv7-A Cortex A8.

```
void matrix_mult_neon (void)
{
    int i;

    float32x4x2_t vectB1, vectB2, vectB3, vectB4, vectB5, vectB6, vectB7, vectB8;
    vectB1 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[0]);
    vectB2 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[1]);
    vectB3 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[2]);
    vectB4 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[3]);
    vectB5 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[4]);
    vectB6 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[5]);
    vectB7 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[6]);
    vectB8 = vld2q_f32(matrixB[7]);


    float32x4x2_t vectT1, vectT2, vectT3, vectT4, vectT5, vectT6, vectT7, vectT8; 
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        vectT1.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB1.val[0], matrixA[i][0]);
        vectT1.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB1.val[1], matrixA[i][0]);
        vectT2.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB2.val[0], matrixA[i][1]);
        vectT2.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB2.val[1], matrixA[i][1]);
        vectT3.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB3.val[0], matrixA[i][2]);
        vectT3.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB3.val[1], matrixA[i][2]);
        vectT4.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB4.val[0], matrixA[i][3]);
        vectT4.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB4.val[1], matrixA[i][3]);
        vectT5.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB5.val[0], matrixA[i][4]);
        vectT5.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB5.val[1], matrixA[i][4]);
        vectT6.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB6.val[0], matrixA[i][5]);
        vectT6.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB6.val[1], matrixA[i][5]);
        vectT7.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB7.val[0], matrixA[i][6]);
        vectT7.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB7.val[1], matrixA[i][6]);
        vectT8.val[0] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB8.val[0], matrixA[i][7]);
        vectT8.val[1] = vmulq_n_f32(vectB8.val[1], matrixA[i][7]);


        vectT1.val[0] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[0], vectT2.val[0]);
        vectT1.val[0] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[0], vectT3.val[0]);
        vectT1.val[0] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[0], vectT4.val[0]);
        vectT1.val[0] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[0], vectT5.val[0]);
        vectT1.val[0] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[0], vectT6.val[0]);
        vectT1.val[0] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[0], vectT7.val[0]);
        vectT1.val[0] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[0], vectT8.val[0]);

        vectT1.val[1] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[1], vectT2.val[1]);
        vectT1.val[1] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[1], vectT3.val[1]);
        vectT1.val[1] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[1], vectT4.val[1]);
        vectT1.val[1] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[1], vectT5.val[1]);
        vectT1.val[1] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[1], vectT6.val[1]);
        vectT1.val[1] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[1], vectT7.val[1]);
        vectT1.val[1] = vaddq_f32(vectT1.val[1], vectT8.val[1]);

        vst2q_f32(matrixC_neon[i], vectT1);
    }
}
```

My normal matrix multiplication function:

```
void matrix_mult (void)
{
    float tempProduct;
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            tempProduct = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            {
                tempProduct = tempProduct + matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
            }
            matrixC[i][j] = tempProduct;
        }
    }
}
```

I use `gettimeofday()` function in the library `<sys/time.h>` to calculate time in nanoseconds.

Comment: Slower than what?  And what exact ARM chip did you time on, and with what compiler options?  Maybe your compiler auto-vectorized better than you manually vectorized.  Also, how exactly did you time it?

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify. What I want to know is that where in the NEON function did I do wrong, or not optimize enough?

Comment: What compiler did you use, and what options?  Did you enable `-ffast-math`?  (NEON FP isn't fully IEEE-compliant, and I think without `-ffast-math` the compiler might unpack to scalar)

Comment: Yeah it is faster with -ffast-math. But can you explain what -ffast-math do to the floating-point operations actually?

Comment: `-ffast-math` lets the compiler emit NEON asm instructions that match your intrinsics.  Otherwise it does something a lot slower.

Comment: The VFP on the Cortex-A8 is a snail!!!. It's actually a VFP-lite that doesn't pipeline at all.  You should avoid using it at all costs. Maybe your compiler auto-vectorized your C code if it isn't terribly slow. I know what's the problem in your code, and am writing a comprehensive answer. Just wait a while.

Comment: A major issue with this is memory bandwidth.  The compiler is taking care of this.  Neon maybe faster, but your routine has probably allocated registers poorly and is not memory bandwidth optimized.  These can easily loose out to any gains from Neon.

Comment: @PeterCordes You can take a look at my answer below. Then you will understand better why I'm not very pleased about `AVX`. `NEON` simply has better instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right about Neon for AArch32 not being IEEE-compliant - but that is a problem for auto-vectorized code rather than intrinsics code. Neon intrinsics are always permitted to emit the relevant Neon instructions.

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh: Ok good, that make sense.  I don't know ARM well enough to notice there were VFP intrinsics mixed in, not NEON.  Any idea why `-ffast-math` helped?  Did it let gcc turn the VFP vectors into NEON vectors for sort of the reason I mentioned?  Or something else.  (I'm only mildly curious.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Pure guesswork as I don't see a compiler version number listed here - but it looks like GCC 6 makes some slightly different scheduling decisions when `-ffast-math` is on. GCC 7 generates near identical code regardless of `-ffast-math` (for the testcase shown - all bets are off if I should be looking at some other code).

Answer (score 5):

**The Problem:**

- `aarch32` has a NEON register bank of the size 256bytes total
- A 8x8 float matrix is already 256bytes large, and you need three of them. (768)
- You have to read the matrix B "vertically", which means it's physically impossible to do it the "streaming" way for maximum data locality.
- You do vector-scalar multiply which takes four times as much total than vector-vector multiplication.
- You load Mat A via `VFP`. And `VFP` on the `Cortex-A8` particularly is unbelievably slow, in addtion to the `NEON`<->`VFP` switching overhead. Unlike auto-vectorization, intrinsic do pretty much everything the way you tell it to do. And you gave the wrong instruction.

**The Solution:**

We transpose matrix B and do dot-product math line by line.

I hope the code below works for you, and if performance is crucial, consider writing in assembly since compilers aren't very trustworthy when it comes to NEON performance, even in intrinsics.

```
static __always_inline float32x2_t dotProduct(float32x4x2_t input1, float32x4x2_t input2)
{
    float32x2_t d0, d1;
    float32x4_t q0;
    input1.val[0] = vmulq_f32(input1.val[0], input2.val[0]);
    input1.val[1] = vmulq_f32(input1.val[1], input2.val[1]);

    q0 = vaddq_f32(input1.val[0], input1.val[1]);
    d0 = vget_low_f32(q0);
    d1 = vget_high_f32(q0);
    d0 = vpadd_f32(d0, d1);
    d0 = vpadd_f32(d0, d1);
    return d0;
}

void matMulF_neon(float *pDst, float *pMatA, float *pMatB)
{
    float32x4x4_t   line01, line23, line45, line67;
    float32x4x2_t   b[8], *pA, *pB, temp;
    float32x2x4_t   result;
    uint32_t        i;

    // vld4 for easier transpose
    line01 = vld4q_f32(pMatB++);
    line23 = vld4q_f32(pMatB++);
    line45 = vld4q_f32(pMatB++);
    line67 = vld4q_f32(pMatB);

    // transpose MatB
    vuzpq_f32(line01.val[0], line45.val[0]);
    vuzpq_f32(line01.val[1], line45.val[1]);
    vuzpq_f32(line01.val[2], line45.val[2]);
    vuzpq_f32(line01.val[3], line45.val[3]);

    vuzpq_f32(line23.val[0], line67.val[0]);
    vuzpq_f32(line23.val[1], line67.val[1]);
    vuzpq_f32(line23.val[2], line67.val[2]);
    vuzpq_f32(line23.val[3], line67.val[3]);

    // store MatB to stack
    b[0].val[0] = line01.val[0];
    b[0].val[1] = line01.val[1];
    b[1].val[0] = line01.val[2];
    b[1].val[1] = line01.val[3];
    b[2].val[0] = line23.val[0];
    b[2].val[1] = line23.val[1];
    b[3].val[0] = line23.val[2];
    b[3].val[1] = line23.val[3];

    b[4].val[0] = line45.val[0];
    b[4].val[1] = line45.val[1];
    b[5].val[0] = line45.val[2];
    b[5].val[1] = line45.val[3];
    b[6].val[0] = line67.val[0];
    b[6].val[1] = line67.val[1];
    b[7].val[0] = line67.val[2];
    b[7].val[1] = line67.val[3];

    pA = (float32x4x2_t *) pMatA;
    i = 8;
    do
    {
        // just the right amount of data for aarch32 NEON register bank size
        pB = b;
        temp = *pA++;
        result.val[0] = dotProduct(*pB++, temp);
        result.val[1] = dotProduct(*pB++, temp);
        result.val[2] = dotProduct(*pB++, temp);
        result.val[3] = dotProduct(*pB++, temp);
        vst4_lane_f32(pDst++, result, 0);

        result.val[0] = dotProduct(*pB++, temp);
        result.val[1] = dotProduct(*pB++, temp);
        result.val[2] = dotProduct(*pB++, temp);
        result.val[3] = dotProduct(*pB, temp);
        vst4_lane_f32(pDst++, result, 0);
    } while (--i);
}
```

/////////////////////////// EDIT

I checked the disassembly and the generated code is FUBAR. (Linaro GCC 7.1.1)

I'd go the assembly route. Writing NEON codes in intrinsics is pure waste of time IMO.